# reuse same "select bulk collect into" statement multiple times?

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can be reused the same "`select bulk collect into`" statement multiple times? So define once at the beginning and reuse shorter form later on? Well the statement is almost the same, every time the filter is different like this:

```
...where filter_condition = variable(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.

Though, a simple option might be to create a **view** that utilizes the `select` statement you currently use, e.g.

```
SQL> create or replace view v_bulk as
  2    select d.deptno, d.dname, e.ename, e.job, e.sal
  3    from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno;

View created.
```

Then, in PL/SQL procedure, reuse the view:

```
SQL> declare
  2    type tr   is record
  3      (deptno number, dname varchar2(20), ename varchar2(20), job varchar2(20), sal number);
  4    type   tt is table of tr;
  5    l_tab   tt;
  6  begin
  7    select * bulk collect into l_tab from v_bulk   --> this is always the same
  8    where job = 'CLERK';                           --> WHERE clause is changing
  9
 10    select * bulk collect into l_tab from v_bulk   --> this is always the same
 11    where sal > 2000;                              --> WHERE clause is changing
 12  end;
 13  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the `SELECT` part of the query with dynamic SQL. Dynamic SQL may be a little slower and a little riskier (in terms of SQL injection possibilities) than the view-based solution offered by Littlefoot, but this approach doesn't require creating extra objects.

```
declare
    v_numbers sys.odcivarchar2list;
    v_sql clob := 'select 1 from dba_objects where 1=1';
begin
    execute immediate v_sql||' and owner = ''SYSTEM''' bulk collect into v_numbers;
    execute immediate v_sql||' and owner = ''DBSNMP''' bulk collect into v_numbers;
end;
/
```